# Does Mapbasic work with MapInfo Discover?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, mapinfo-discover

Does Mapbasic work with MapInfo Discover?

From what I've been able to figure out it does not.

I was really hoping to make some macro style things to help automate some of our process but it doesn't look like it is possible with Discover functions.

Comment: You could ask Datamine: https://www.dataminesoftware.com/solutions/discover-exploration-gis/

Answer (score 1):

MapInfo Discover, or Datamine Discover as it is called these days, is an add-on for MapInfo Pro. As far as I know, they do not have an API for the tool which would make it possible for you to automate certain tasks.

You can automate MapInfo Pro using MapBasic, .NET and recently Python support has also been added. This gives you access to automating data processing of vector data.

If you want to automate data processing of raster data, you can use the MapInfo Pro Raster SDK that comes with MapInfo Pro. This API is based on .NET.